# How to run a bash script in the host from a docker container and get the result

Tags: docker

I have a Jenkins that is running inside of a docker container. Outside of the Docker container in the host, I have a bash script that I would like to run from a Jenkins pipeline inside of the container and get the result of the bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that.  One of the major benefits of containers (and also of virtualization systems) is that processes running in containers *can't* make arbitrary changes or run arbitrary commands on the host.

If managing the host in some form is a major goal of your task, then you need to run it directly on the host, not in an isolation system designed to prevent you from doing this.

(There are ways to cause side effects like this to happen: if you have an ssh daemon on the host, your containerized process could launch a remote command via ssh; or you could package whatever command in a service triggered by a network request; but these are basically the same approaches you'd use to make your host system manageable by "something else", and triggering it from a local Docker container isn't different from triggering it from a different host.)